# mod_rewrite rule for "www to non www" doesn't redirect sub-pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made a thorough search before I have asked this question here. Please hear me out:

I am trying to redirect my blog from www to non www and it doesn't redirect any sub-pages. I have an http > https redirect in place as well and it works perfectly for both domain as well as the sub-pages. Here are the rules I have in my .htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^^rcp-pep-ipn //?rcp-pep-listener=IPN [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

I'd really appreciate an explanation if I am doing anything wrong here. I have literally pulled my hair since I have used the exact same code (from the second RewriteBase /) for all other sites and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bring those protocol checking conditions to the beginning. You have some problems within the rules too. Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
  RewriteRule ^rcp-pep-ipn /?rcp-pep-listener=IPN [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you @revo. Could you please explain to me the changes you did in the code and the mistakes I made? I'd like to learn this stuff.

Comment: Apologies for the delay @revo. Was taking a backup just to be on the safe side. Your code worked like a CHARM! Thanks a lot! Could you please explain the changes you made?

And I added RewriteBase / just below RewriteEngine On

Comment: I see you have removed RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] and kept the RewriteRule . /index.php [L] at the bottom. Will that cause any issues?

Also, just for my information, as those rules needed to be moved to the top, will the old rules (which were moved to the bottom) pose any problems?

Comment: That rule was superfluous so I removed it. The major changes are changing https rules positions. They should be on top. Directives on https had some issues. You were double checking `www.` and `%1` back-reference was empty when no `www.` was found resulting in no host name.

Comment: Thank you for the lucid explanation @revo. So the rules which were moved to bottom fire without any issues, right?

Sorry if I am being paranoid here as this site is my bread and butter.

Comment: My pleasure. No, not probably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174522/discussion-between-naser-mohd-baig-and-revo).